# Does Open Layer 3 not support offline map?

Tags: openlayers-3

We are going to display a map (with custom tiles overlays) in a webview on mobile device, when there are no connections, we had to support loading low-res version of the map (with custom tiles overlays) from the device. while open layer 2 does have some examples about it. We can't found any with open layer 3. We would like to know more on it, so it would not too late to take any alternative solutions.

Comment: There have been many threads on this already, just use a custom tileLoadFunction. See e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116508/how-do-i-pull-tiles-from-a-local-pouchdb-in-openlayers-3